# CSS 100% width in floated div

Tags: css

```
<div style="float:left">

    <div class="designerWrapper">   
        <div class="pageBox">

            content

        </div>            
    </div>

</div>
<div style="float:left; margin-left:10px;">

    content 2

</div>
<div style="clear:both"></div>            
<br /><br />
```

How do I make the div that holds content 2 100% width?  If I set it to 100% width it is too wide, at the moment it expands with it's contents length.

Comment: Do you want both floated divs to be next to each other or one behind the other ?

Comment: Next to each other, like <td></td><td></td>

Comment: Could you make a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) example of your problem?

Comment: Have you tried width: auto; ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you sould use the table stuff

```
<div id="outer1">
<div id="outer2">
    <div id="left"></div>
    <div id="right"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

css:

```
#outer1 {display:table;width:600px;height:30px;}
#outer2 {display:table-row;width:600px;height:30px;}
#left {display:table-cell; width:15px;}
#right {display:table-cell; width:auto;}
```

important there is no floating! because the table display floats the cells automatically.
i didnt test the code hope works.

Answer (score 0):

You can set min-width depend upon your requirement.
later on it will expand with its content

```
<div style="float:left; margin-left:10px;min-width:110px;">

    content 2

</div>
```