# html and divs content

Tags: css, html

I have such structure (divs):

```
#content-wrapper->
  #left
  #center
  #right
#footer

#footer
{
    position: relative;
}

#content-wrapper
{
    position: relative;
    clear: both;
    overflow: hidden;

    width: 100%;
        height: 100%;

    min-height: 300px;
}
```

But when text in `#center` div is bigger, than `min-height`, it becomes over the `#footer`. What's wrong?

---

**UPD:**
Example address: [link](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/932520/site.zip)

Comment: You've missed a lot of the necessary code needed to figure this one out.

Comment: what is `#content-wrapper`'s height 100% of?  If it's 100% of the body, then where does the `#footer` fit in?

Comment: I think this is a pretty close approximation of your structure, but I'm not seeing the problem you mentioned.  Could you tweak this fiddle, or link to a real example of the problem?  http://jsfiddle.net/mlms13/TfESA/

Comment: @michael-martin-smucker look at update, please.

Comment: @Ockonal, I can't get the link to work... it just times out for me.

Comment: @michael-martin-smucker http://dl.dropbox.com/u/932520/site.zip oh sorry, here is the local html-version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for providing the content.  It looks like this problem is happening because `#content-center` has a fixed height of 200px.  Get rid of this (and the fixed height for `#content-left` and `#content-right` unless you have a really good reason to keep it), or change it to `min-height` instead, and the footer should show up below the content as expected.

You'll still run into some problems if `#content-left` or `#content-right` is the longest column.  To deal with that, you could remove the footer from the `#content-wrapper` div -- set your structure up like this:

```
<div id="content-wrapper">
    <div id="content-left"></div>
    <div id="content-right"></div>
    <div id="content-center"></div>
</div>
<div id="footer"></div>
```

Let me know if that doesn't work for you.

Answer (score 2):

you need a new item. a clearer wich clears the floating inside the main div

- you dont need any of position:relative
- you dont need any of the clear:both
- but you need a new item inside the content-wrapper

this.
thats all.

**floated divs like a points. they not affect the size of a div or the width**

another nice solution to use the table stuff:

[CSS 100% width in floated div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4861282/css-100-width-in-floated-div/4863045#4863045)

this is not really the answer, but i prefer you to use table displayed divs, and they can be resized, placed better than only floated divs.

Comment: I might not be understanding the original example, but in general setting the `overflow` should eliminate the need for empty divs cluttering up your html, shouldn't it?

Comment: A clearfix DIV? Isn't that deprecated for over 5 years now (in favor of `overflow:auto`)?

Comment: @ sime vidas : might be. i dont know. i will search for this

Comment: @fehergeri Here, read this: http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2005/03/clearing_floats.html (that article is 6 years old `:)`)

Comment: @sime vidas: i found this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/211383/which-method-of-clearfix-is-best.

Comment: @fehergeri overflow:auto is the superior method. IE6 requires a few workaround CSS properties, but that is (obviously) still better than adding dedicated markup.

Comment: @fehergeri, look at update, plaese. I've added design address.